# LanguageApp.translate doesn't work for script sharing user?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-translate

I need to format a date in GAS, as month/year, with month as a word, in italian.

I used the Language.App.translate, as the Utilities.formatDate formats the month in English language.
The code fragment is the following:

```
  var dteng = Utilities.formatDate(dt, "CET", "MMMM/yyyy");
  dttran = LanguageApp.translate(dteng, 'en', 'it');
```

When I execute the script with my user, it works fine, and the translation is done.
When I execute it as a different user (the one who is actually using the script), the translation doesn't happen.

The execution transcript reports:

> LanguageApp.translate([January/2007, en, it])

but the result is the same, untranslated string.

All the remaining part of the script executes without problems.

Any hint? Should I open an issue?

tks

Massimo

Comment: the problem appears fixed replacing the slash in the input string with a space (the slash is inserted again after the translation).

Comment: Anyhow, I don't understand why the behaviour was different, with the same input data, if executed as the developer, or as a sharing (read only on the script) user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the behavior of:

```
function getTranslate() {
  var dteng = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(2007, 0, 1), 'CET', 'MMMM/yyyy');
  var dttran = LanguageApp.translate(dteng, 'en', 'it');
  /*var dttran = LanguageApp.translate(dteng, 'en', 'es'); // `Enero/2007` <- works as expected.*/
  Logger.log(dttran); // January/2007
}
```

is equal in all cases, for any user, always returns `January/2007`.

Apparently certain characters are not interpreted correctly, with formats like: `'MMMM/yyyy'`, `'MMMM.yyyy'` or `'MMMM_yyyy'` not perform the appropriate translation.

With other formats (e.g. `'MMMM-yyyy'`), works as expected.

**UPDATE**

Using Google Translate from the Web:

[image]